# Visual artifact when dismissing more than one modal view controller at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I've been struggling to find an answer to this question. I build a stack of modals via:

```
[[[NavA viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] presentViewController:NavB animated:YES completion:NULL];
[[[NavB viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] presentViewController:NavC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

When I want to dismiss the **NavA** and **NavB** modals simultaneously I call

```
[[[NavA viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

This works fine except there's a brief flash where you can see **NavB** as the full stack is dismissed.

I stepped through the debugger and it looks like before the animation begins **NavC** disappears instantly and **NavB** dismisses with animation.

Is there any way to avoid this visual artifact and have the whole stack dismiss smoothly with **NavC** visible for the full duration of the animation?

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm presenting `UINavigationController` rather than `UIViewController` because this flow is for user login and has multiple possible branches that can lead back either to the current stage e.g. **NavC** (LoginPage), **NavB** (LandingPage with login and signup buttons) or all the way back to the root, **NavA** (main page of the application). In the iOS documentation they present a similar design pattern with the camera where each stage presents a `UINavigationController` with multiple possible view controllers https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: I need to understand this better. Do you have 1 `UINavigationController` which has 3 view controllers, `A`, `B`, and `C`, on the stack or do you have 3 `UINavigationController`s each presented with `-presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Comment: @JefferyThomas the latter - NavB and NavC are UINavigationControllers presented via `[self presentViewController:navController animated:TRUE completion:^{}];` NavA is the root view controller.

Comment: do you use NO or YES for animation when dismissing?

Comment: @BorisGafurov I'm using YES for animation when dismissing

Comment: have you tried NO? you should see just your A view show up

Answer (score 4):

Actually there's no way to do it by just using `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` method no matter where you put it or how you call it (at least I couldn't, if someone knows a way - we all want to know).

---

**HOWEVER,** there's a **hack** you can use to achieve your desired outcome (this code should be called from "B" ViewController):

```
// Snapshot of "C" ViewController
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size, YES, 0);
UIView *snapshot = [self.presentedViewController.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Cover the entire view of "B" (and hide navigation bar)
[self.view addSubview:snapshot];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

// Dismiss "C" without animation
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    // Dismiss "B" with animation
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: Be careful of this solution. In iOS 7, dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO does not do layouts synchronously, and may crash when you call the 2nd dismiss as the view controller is still treated as "mid-transition".

Comment: @JohnEstropia since the first one is without animation, do you think it will still affect? is it better to just add the second line inside the completion block of the first one then?

Comment: Moving the second dismiss into the first's completion will definitely prevent said problem (although the presentingViewController may flash for a split second). I don't know if it was fixed on iOS 8, but we had problems with chained dismissals back then.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Storyboard then this should be achievable using Unwind Segues. Mike Woelmer has a [good set of articles](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/) about this. Basically you provide information to the Storyboard about how a view can unwind through several different views to get a to a view that's already on the stack.

However, I'm a bit confused in the same way that Jeffery Thomas is in the comments: why are you presenting a navigation controller with another navigation controller?  I can understand that you might want the navigation bar to look different on different views, but you can customise that when the view is due to appear. You should think a bit about the content of the views in NavB and NavC and ask yourself whether they are supposed to be presented as modal views or whether they would be better off as part of a single navigation stack. By presenting each Navigation Controller modally you're ending up with multiple navigation stacks, not a single stack with multiple view controllers. Even if just NavB and NavC were part of the same stack it would probably remove the visual glitch you're seeing.

If you did use a single navigation controller then you can get back to a previous view controller in the navigation stack by using the method [`-popToViewController:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:) on UINavigationController.

If you decide that presenting NavB and NavC modally as you are currently doing is the right thing to do then you are likely to get into trouble because when you ask NavA to dismiss its view controller it will try to dismiss NavB, which to it means setting up a transition between the NavB's view and NavA's view. That's why you're seeing that transition, and not the one you want (which is between NavC's view and NavA's). One way which might work (and sounds a bit weird) is to try to present NavA from NavC, then override the transition to make it look like you're popping NavC off the stack. Once you're there you can clean things up by removing any strong references to NavB and NavC. [This article from Ash Furrow](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/) will get you most of the way.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using storyboards. I am presenting navigation controllers rather than view controllers due to multiple branches that need to lead back to each stage. As an experiment I presented just the UIViewControllers instead and ended up with the same glitchy animation. In this test the flow was as follows [NavA  viewControllers[0] present:VCB] -> [VCB present VCC] -> [NavA  viewControllers[0] dismiss]

Comment: Thank you for your reply by the way, it made me reexamine the user flow and I found that some presentations were not being performed on the main thread elsewhere in the app. Also from the Apple docs presenting Navigation Controllers rather than View Controllers is also a document pattern and they provide an example https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: Sorry I should have been a bit clearer about that. The problem doesn't arise because you are using UINavigationControllers instead of UIViewControllers (as you've now tested). What I was saying was that if you were to us the UINavigationController as it is intended, namely to manage a stack of more than one view controller, then the task of popping two view controllers at once would become trivial because they are part of the same navigation stack. Nested modal views behave quite differently.

Comment: I also entirely accept the point about presenting Navigation Controllers: there is absolutely nothing wrong with this if it makes sense for the content you're presenting, I was just suggesting it might need re-examining. But as it happens there is a clue in the link you posted from Apple: "When it comes time to dismiss a presented view controller, the preferred approach is to let the presenting view controller dismiss it." In your case you're trying to dismiss NavC from NavA, which wasn't the VC that presented it, and that's the underlying reason why your animation is running into problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can fake the animation to look exactly as you wish:

- pop/dismiss B and C **without** animation
- push/present C **without** animation
- pop/dismiss C using whatever animation you wish